# Deleted android app project still appears in Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I deleted several android app projects from Eclipse by right click on project and click "Delete". But when I run the project that I'm working on with simulator, the deleted apps are still there and they can still work. How to delete them from the simulator?

Answer (score 1):

You should uninstall them from the simulator (although the right word would be emulator :P)

Comment: That's because you installed the APK on the device (emulator). It's just like a real device (phone / tablet). So if you install something it's installed. Just uninstall them form the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You have to know that Emulator is not a part of Eclipse it is a separate program for creating a virtual machine for the Android OS. If you want to uninstall specific apps from the emulator goto `Settings>apps` and uninstall them or if you want to delete all the apps (**Recommended**)
while starting the emulator check the option **Wipe user data**[image: Launch Android virtual device Manager and click Start... for specific AVD]